# Google sheets highlight cells if they're above or below another cell value with conditional formating

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to have cells highlighted Green if they're above average, amber if they're up to 1000 less than the average, and red if they're anything below that. However, I can't even seem to manage to get it to highlight red if the value is below the average.

If I use `=$B2>8000` as my conditional format then only cells above 8000 will highlight, as I want, but if I use `=$B2>C32`, with C32 being the average, then it will highlight all of the cells instead. I can't figure out a way to get it to only highlight the correct cells when comparing it to the cell with all of my required formats.

Comment: make sure that C32 is a numerical value, you can check by typing `=ISNUMBER(C32)` in a blank cell and lock it in your conditional formatting rule: `=$B2>$C$32`

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet